# Knockout Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, html, knockout.js, knockout-validation

I'm using Knockout Validation and when I post the view model to the controller I'm getting the exception "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded". I have one Main View Model because I'm using the CustomerViewModel in the same view (2 bootstrap modals), the first is to create a customer and the other one is to edit customer. Any idea of why is throwing the exception?

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SaveCustomer(Customer model)
{
    string status = "ok";

    return Json(status, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

public class Customer
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    var CustomerSetupViewModel = function () {
        var self = this;

        self.Name = ko.observable("");

        self.Validation = ko.validatedObservable([
            self.Name.extend({
                required: true
            })    
        ]);

        var CustomerSetup = {
            Name: self.Name
        };

        self.CustomerSetup = ko.observable();

        self.GetCustomer = function () {            
            var data = { Name: "ToBeUpdated" };
            self.CustomerSetup(data);
        }

        self.Save = function () {
            
            if (self.Validation.isValid()) {
                
                $.post("/Home/SaveCustomer", self, function (data) {
                    if (data == "ok")                    
                        alert("successful");                    
                    else
                        alert("error");
                });

            }
            else {
                self.Validation.errors.showAllMessages();
            }
        }

        self.Update = function () {            
            var name = self.CustomerSetup().Name;            
            alert(name);
        }        
    }

    var MainViewModel = function () {        
        self = this;
        self.NewCustomer = new CustomerSetupViewModel();
        self.EditCustomer = new CustomerSetupViewModel();
    }

    vm = new MainViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(vm);

    $("#updateCustomer").click(function () {        
        vm.EditCustomer.GetCustomer();
    });

    $("#NewCustomer").on("show.bs.modal", function (e) {
        vm.NewCustomer.Name("");        
        vm.NewCustomer.Validation.errors.showAllMessages(false);
    })

});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<hr />
<a id="addCustomer" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#NewCustomer">Add Customer</a>
<a id="updateCustomer" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#UpdateCustomer">Update Customer</a>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="NewCustomer" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="NewModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="NewModalLabel">New Customer</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading"></div>
                    <div class="panel-body">

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <label>Customer Name</label>
                                <input type="text" id="Name" class="form-control" data-bind="value: NewCustomer.Name" />
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <a role="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
                        <a role="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click: NewCustomer.Save()">Save</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="UpdateCustomer" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="UpdateModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="UpdateModalLabel">Update Customer</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading"></div>
                    <div class="panel-body" data-bind="foreach: EditCustomer.CustomerSetup">

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <label>Customer Name</label>
                                <input type="text" id="Name" class="form-control" data-bind="value: Name" />
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <a role="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
                        <a role="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click: EditCustomer.Update">Update</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout-validation/2.0.3/knockout.validation.js"></script>
```

Comment: The error has nothing to do with KO. It is happening at the server level. Please show your server model object and the controller code. Also, on another note, why do you have a method named `GetCustomer` but it does not return anything? I would rename that.

Comment: The method GetCustomer will be applied to make an ajax call to get the data from each customer. All the code is an example. The problem is not in the server because if I delete the KO validation code the post is succesful, anyway this is the server code: [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult SaveCustomer(Customer model)
        {
            string status = "ok";
            
            return Json(status, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

Comment: What do you mean "this is the sever code"? The sever code is what you have in `SaveCustomer` and whatever is receieved by that method as input.

Comment: And what do you mean for "server model object"? Anyway the Save function is clearly that makes a post to the server if KO validation is ok, there is no science in that..

Comment: Ok you seem to know what you are doing so I will leave you alone because I don't understand the "science"...

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution after using ko.toJSON() in the Save function. ko.toJSON() produces a JavaScript object with no Knockout constructs. And in that way I avoid the infinite loop.

```
self.Save = function () {

        if (self.Validation.isValid()) {

            $.post("/Home/SaveCustomer", ko.toJSON(self), function (data) {
                if (data == "ok")                    
                    alert("successful");                    
                else
                    alert("error");
            });

        }
        else {
            self.Validation.errors.showAllMessages();
        }
    }
```